# Windows 10 Background Logon - Can it be disabled?

Tags: windows-10, login

This is tricky to search due to most results being about the login screen background image, apologies if it's been answered elsewhere.

When loading Windows 10, before I have logged in Windows automatically starts loading my account. This can be seen by Steam and Discord going online, as well as everything being loaded instantly if I wait a minute or so on the login screen. This is done prior to entering a password.

I do not want this functionality. It has lead to many issues with regards to samba shares, since it tries to connect to mounted network drives before the network stack has loaded. This means every single login, I get an error saying drives can't be mounted even though going into explorer loads them without issue.

Is this possible to disable?
It does not have anything to do with automatic login, I have triple checked and that is disabled. In addition, this behaviour happens with a fress installation of Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: This may be useful, but I don’t think it has a full answer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/preloading-user-profiles-in-background/00697550-d32d-4490-a10f-82bfd15ef09c  Edit: This may also be of use; https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49963-use-sign-info-auto-finish-after-update-restart-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: This has been asked here before but I'm having trouble finding the entry. Basically, there is a setting in Cortana that enables/disables automatic logon.

Comment: Tested it a bit - Trenly's edit was exactly the option that fixed it. Seems to be working perfectly now!

Comment: @Jademalo Would you mind posting your conclusions as a regular answer here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As posted by @Trenly, this guide resolved my issue -

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49963-use-sign-info-auto-finish-after-update-restart-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give an answer here. I think you should be a little more specific here. The linked tutorial describes four ways to accomplish the goal. You should therefore at least add the information about which one you have chosen and ideally why.

Comment: It's been 5 years, I genuinely cannot remember.